# Do air handlers call for specific return sizes?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

Please excuse me if my terminology is off, this is not my area of expertise.

Some background:

In my new construction home, the air has gone out twice in less than a month. The company that I had come out to get it running again has advised me that the handler has a return that is too small for the 4 ton unit we currently have.

Getting into my crawl space, I can see that the unit is sweating excessively. This excess moisture seems to be causing the electrical components to fail, such as the main board and the breakers. In addition, both times the air has gone out, the line leading into the condenser has been a solid block of ice.

In a possible attempt to see if the original installer knowingly installed a return too small for the unit, I'm curious if there is any documentation outlining a minimum return size?

My air handler is an Ameristar, model #M4AH4P48B1C00AA. The condenser is the same make, model #M4AC4048D1000A. The current filter size that my return accepts is a 24x30x1.

The company I am using for the repair is advising me to have a second return installed, and a whole home dehumidifier installed inline with the handler.

Thanks in advance for any advice. Just trying to minimize the amount of money I'm potentially about to spend in repairs.

Comment: Would agree with the installer, having second air return would help the air handler circulating the air. I till only take as much as it needs. Look at your Air Handler CFM specs.

Comment: I had problems with my new unit when our house was built 25 years ago. I called the manufacturer"s distributor since I suspected the possibility of an incorrect installation.  I asked, "If your mother was having problems with her AC, would you use to diagnose it?" They gave me an HVAC contractor who I paid to look at the whole system and compare it to the installation specs. He wrote a whole page of problems. I took it to the installer and he had to fix the problems at his expense. The system lasted for 20 years after that.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of your air handler and your outdoor unit? With the air handler make sure to capture a general area of the ductwork connected to the handler,

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the specs for your unit,your supply size is 19.5" x 10 5/16" and your return is 20" x 22" based on the filter size and dimensions of the unit. You never did mention the actual size of your return duct. If the installer transitioned the return duct to accept a 24" x 30" filter, better still. Unless there is some really weird routing of the return duct work or restricted return vents, the return size looks OK. Most new AC units have some ability to control humidity so I'd do more research before installing a whole house dehumidifier. Verify all your supply ducts are open.

Comment: I wish I read this before posting my answer. A 20"x10" supply is only good for 1,060 CFM 

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  And the specs state 1336-1918 CFM.  So somethings weird.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the PDF you found? I'm having trouble finding anything reliable.

Comment: @MonkeyZeushttps://www.gemaire.com/ameristar-m4ah4p48b1c00aa-multi-position-air-handler-4-ton-14-seer-r410a-psc-m4ah4p48b1c00a

Answer (score 1):

You need 400 CFM of air flow per ton of cooling. For you, that means your air handler should be pushing a minimum of 1,600 cfm.

By [my calculation](https://hvacdirect.com/hvac/pdf/Field_duct-sizing-chart.pdf), a 24"x30" return can handle ~4,300 CFM. The return, at least at the location of the filter, is **not** the problem. However, you might have some upstream constraints or reductions which are causing a problem.

---

> Getting into my crawl space, I can see that the unit is sweating excessively. This excess moisture seems to be causing the electrical components to fail, such as the main board and the breakers. In addition, both times the air has gone out, the line leading into the condenser has been a solid block of ice.

Prepare yourself, you're about to have a bad time:

- #M4AC4048D1000A is a single-stage unit

  - If this is oversized for your home then it would be having cooling cycles of less than 15-minutes; aka short-cycling. This is bad and causes premature failure.
  - 4 Tons of cooling is proper for a ~2,000 sq. ft. house. This varies based on how good your insulation is and your climate region.
- The evaporator coil is mismatched for the outdoor condenser

  - Common issue; albeit expensive. $1,000-$4,000
- The lineset is not sized properly

  - This is a strange problem to have but not impossible. $1,000-$2,000
- The system has too little refrigerant

  - You have a leak somewhere, not fun. $2,000+
- The system has too much refrigerant

  - Easy fix, evacuate some of it. $500?
- The ductwork was designed in such a way that it has too much static pressure

  - Just start crying now to save yourself some time if you're getting a quote to fix this.

The sweating could simply be a symptom of the unit living in the crawl space since the surrounding humidity is not controlled.

---

> The company I am using for the repair is advising me to have a second return installed, and a whole home dehumidifier installed inline with the handler.

Did this company actually diagnose your system or does it feel like they operate on the "replace-n-pray" business model.

---

Get a competent senior HVAC tech to inspect your entire HVAC system for an hourly rate and write up a report. Easier said than done, I know...

A new construction home is supposed to be move-in ready, not a nightmare come to life.